# Spark Streaming Direct Kafka API, OffsetRanges : How to handle first run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

My spark-streaming application reads from Kafka using the direct stream approach without the help of ZooKeeper. I would like to handle failures such that Exactly-once Semantics is followed in my application. I am following [this](https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/TransactionalPerBatch.scala) for reference. Everything looks perfect except for :

```
val stream: InputDStream[(String,Long)] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, Long)](
      ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets,
      // we're just going to count messages per topic, don't care about the contents, so convert each message to (topic, 1)
      (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => (mmd.topic, 1L))
```

In the very first run of the application, since there will be no offsets read, what value to pass in for the `fromOffsets` Map parameter? I am certainly missing something.

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: The first offset is `0L` -- you want to use that as the `fromOffset` for each `TopicAndPartition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first offset isn't necessarily 0L, depending on how long the topics have existed.

I personally just pre-insert the appropriate offsets into the database separately. Then the spark job reads the offsets from the database at startup.

The file kafkacluster.scala in the spark Kafka integration has methods that make it easier to query Kafka for the earliest available offset. That file was private, but has been made public in the most recent spark code.

Comment: Offsets are  are never less than 0L -- so if you always use 0L it will always start at the beginning even if the beginning is 32L or whatever

Comment: @CodyKoeninger Yes, even I decided to manually insert the offsets for the first run. Still investigating if there is any better method, since for each partition of each topic I have to manually do this :(

Comment: @DavidGriffin No, I tried 0L. It gives me OffsetOutOfRange exception. Since the offset won't be available anymore, based on the retention period, I guess it won't work.

Comment: You can always use an Offset Fetch and get the values before you start.

Comment: @Cody Don't offsets get stored in the checkpoint directory if enabled?

Comment: @aswin you can write code to get the earliest offsets, see the file I mentioned

Comment: @yuval yeah as long as you dont mind losing checkpoints whenever your code has to change.  The repo linked in the original post has links to a a presentation and a long blog post that explains this

Comment: @CodyKoeninger Thanks :) And thank you for the direct kafka stream implementation as well.

Comment: @CodyKoeninger BTW, AFAIK by code changes you mean spark DAG changes, right? Because I'm assuming code running inside the graph's closure can change without losing the checkpointed data.

Comment: @yuval basically if your jar has to change, assume you cant recover the checkpoint

Comment: @cody Can you elaborate? Or better, is there any place I can read about that?

Comment: @yuval http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#upgrading-application-code

Comment: @CodyKoeninger I am not the best at Scala, but when I try to access the KafkaCluster class like  `val kC = new KafkaCluster(kafkaParams)`, I get 
class KafkaCluster in package kafka cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka exception. And, my Intellij tells me that it is inaccessible. Why is it?

Comment: @aswin that class is private, was only made public very recently in the latest spark code.

Comment: `KafkaCLuster` is again a DeveloperAPI so it is not public.

Comment: The DeveloperApi annotation has nothing to do with whether the class is public in the jvm sense.  It's not private.  See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaCluster.scala#L45